# Prove that if x is the square of any positive integer, then x mod 3 cannot equal 2

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I tried to prove this by contradiction:

Suppose $x = k^2$ for some positive integer $k$.

Suppose $x\mod 3 = 2$

2 = x - 3 $\lfloor x/3 \rfloor$

$n \le x/3 \lt n+1$

$3n \le x \lt 3n+3$

But then I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: You've nowhere used that $x$ is a square. That might help. :)

Comment: I think the natural thing is not contradiction, it is *cases*. Suppose that $x=n^2$, There are $3$ possibilities: (i) $n\bmod{3}=0$; (ii) $n\bmod{3}=1$; (iii) $n\bmod{3}=2$.

Comment: Yeah I realized that as soon as I walked out of the exam but I'm still not sure how I would even use the fact that $x$ is a square

Comment: @AndréNicolas Then would I have to show that $x$ mod 3 must equal either 0 or 1? How would I do that

Comment: $2^2=4=1$ in $mod 3$.

Comment: Take for example $n\bmod{3}=2$. Then $n=3k+2$ for some $k$. Then $x=n^2=9k^2+6k+4=3(3k^2+2k+1)+1$, so $x\bmod{3}=1$. The other two are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to go case by case.
First take k of the form 3p.
It's square would also be of the same form.
For k = 3p+1,
Again by squaring you get it to be of the form 3p+1.
For k=3p+2, the square is again of the form.
Since these are the only possible forms an integer can be and none of these have a square of the form 3p+2,

No square of an integer has the form 3p+2.

Answer (score 1):

HINT : if $a = b \; mod \; n$ then $a^2 = b^2 \; mod \; n$ and there is not that much possibilities as André Nicolas pointed out